# Sorting a sentence by number of vowels in a word and indexing it from the left using javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, arraylist, indexing

Example sentence: "My passion is to work towards my goal is the whole idea"

I want to sort the words according to the word having highest vowels will be showed first followed by descending order of the vowels present in it and indexing it from left. Please help me with the javaScript code.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please share your efforts till now. Share your code which you have tried and also the errors if you got any.

Comment: And read the asking requirements in the article [How do I ask a good question on SO](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try with this code below:

```js
let string = "My passion is to work towards my goal is the whole idea";
let myarr = string.split(' ');


function mostWolves(word) {
  let count = 0;
  for(let i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
    let x = word[i].toLowerCase();
    if (x === 'a' || x === 'e' || x === 'i' || x === 'o' || x === 'u'){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

myarr.sort((a, b) => {

  if(mostWolves(a) > mostWolves(b)) {
    return -1;
  }else if(mostWolves(a) < mostWolves(b)) {
    return +1;
  } else {
    if(a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) {
      return +1;
    }else if(a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
});

console.log(myarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may split them first, then count the number of vowels then do sorting.

```
var str = "My passion is to work towards my goal is the whole idea"
```

var vowels = 'aeiou'

```
str.split(' ')
    .map(word => [word, Array.from(word.toLowerCase()).filter(char => vowels.indexOf(char) > -1 ).length])
    .sort((_1,  _2) => _1[1] > _2[1]? -1: 1).map(_ => _[0])
```

> > ["passion", "idea", "towards", "goal", "whole", "is", "to", "work", "is", "the", "My", "my"]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could split, get counting and original index, sort by counting and index, finally take the joined string.

```js
var string = "My passion is to work towards my goal is the whole idea",
    array = string.split(' '),
    hash = array.reduce((o, k, index) => {
        o[k] = { index, count: (k.match(/[aeiou]/g) || []).length };
        return o;
    }, {})
    result = array
        .sort((a, b) => hash[b].count - hash[a].count || hash[b].index - hash[a].index)
        .join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the word 'idea' has to be the first word and then 'passion' and then the following words according to the number of vowels in it, how can it be done

Comment: Answer should look like - idea passion whole goal towards the is work to is my My (using indexing).

Comment: It means each word will be array indexed in 0 1 2 3 4 format and sort from right to left.

Comment: The answer should look like -> " idea passion whole goal towards the is work to is my My", sorting each word from right to left

Comment: yeah thanks for understanding.It is bcz i have to sort the words like right word having 3 vowels 'idea' will come before the left word 'passion',  in the same way right word having 2 vowels 'whole' comes before left word 'goal'.